# \hangindent violates a slender order of dots in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation

I have wrote command `\l@appendix` for formatting appendix entries in TOC. There is minimal test example:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@mainmatter\@mainmattertrue
\newcommand\mainmatter{\@mainmattertrue}
\newcommand\frontmatter{\@mainmatterfalse}
\newcommand\aftermatter{\@mainmatterfalse}

\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum\c@secnumdepth>\m@ne%
                  \if@mainmatter%                 
                     \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                     \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
  {\protect\numberline\thechapter\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{#1}}%
                  \else%
                     \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                     \phantomsection
                     \addcontentsline{toc}{appendix}%
    {\texorpdfstring{\@chapapp\space\protect\numberline\thechapter\space#1}        {\@chapapp\space\thechapter\space#1}}%
                  \fi%
                \else%
                   \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                \fi%
                \chaptermark{#1}%
                \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                  \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                  \@afterheading}

\renewcommand\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
    {\leftskip 0.0em\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg plus 15em \parfillskip -    \rightskip
     \parindent 0.0em\relax\@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty\@M
     \leavevmode
     \@tempdima 1.0em\relax
     \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
     {#1}\nobreak
     \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
        \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
   mu$}\hfill
     \nobreak
     \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil \normalcolor #2}
     \par}%
  \fi}

\newcommand\l@appendix[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
    {\leftskip 0.0em\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg plus 15em \parfillskip -\rightskip
     \parindent 0.0em\relax \hangindent 4.3em\relax\@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty\@M
     \leavevmode
     \@tempdima 1.5em\relax
     \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
     {#1}\nobreak
     \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
        \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
       mu$}\hfill
     \nobreak
     \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil \normalcolor #2}
     \par}%
  \fi}

\renewcommand\appendix{\par%
  \aftermatter%
  \setcounter{chapter}{0}%
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \gdef\@chapapp{\appendixname}%
  \gdef\thechapter{\@Alph\c@chapter}%
}\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First chapter}
\chapter{Second chapter}
\appendix
\chapter{Appendix with very long heading for test describing issue}
\chapter{Appendix}
\end{document}
```

it works but `\hangindent` command violates a slender order of dots in TOC in times when header goes beyond a single line.

[image]

How can I fix it without violating the former indentations?

Comment: please post an example that people can run and test possible answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The hangindent shifts the containing box so loses the leaders alignment.

Here I forced the repeated leaders box to a known width (.7em) and forced the hangindent to be a multiple of that (4.2em rather than 4.3em).

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@mainmatter\@mainmattertrue
\newcommand\mainmatter{\@mainmattertrue}
\newcommand\frontmatter{\@mainmatterfalse}
\newcommand\aftermatter{\@mainmatterfalse}

\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum\c@secnumdepth>\m@ne%
                  \if@mainmatter%                 
                     \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                     \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
  {\protect\numberline\thechapter\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{#1}}%
                  \else%
                     \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                     \phantomsection
                     \addcontentsline{toc}{appendix}%
    {\texorpdfstring{\@chapapp\space\protect\numberline\thechapter\space#1}        {\@chapapp\space\thechapter\space#1}}%
                  \fi%
                \else%
                   \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                \fi%
                \chaptermark{#1}%
                \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                  \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                  \@afterheading}

\renewcommand\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
    {\leftskip 0.0em\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg plus 15em \parfillskip -    \rightskip
     \parindent 0.0em\relax\@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty\@M
     \leavevmode
     \@tempdima 1.0em\relax
     \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
     {#1}\nobreak
     \leaders\hbox to .7em{\hss.\hss}\hfill
     \nobreak
     \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil \normalcolor #2}
     \par}%
  \fi}

\newcommand\l@appendix[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
    {\leftskip 0.0em\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg plus 15em \parfillskip -\rightskip
     \parindent 0.0em\relax \hangindent 4.2em\relax\@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty\@M
     \leavevmode
     \@tempdima 1.5em\relax
     \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
     {#1}\nobreak
     \leaders\hbox to .7em{\hss.\hss}\hfill
     \nobreak
     \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil \normalcolor #2}
     \par}%
  \fi}

\renewcommand\appendix{\par%
  \aftermatter%
  \setcounter{chapter}{0}%
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \gdef\@chapapp{\appendixname}%
  \gdef\thechapter{\@Alph\c@chapter}%
}\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{First chapter}
\chapter{Second chapter}
\appendix
\chapter{Appendix with very long heading for test describing issue}
\chapter{Appendix}
\end{document}
```